# Edit text not found in robotium

Tags: android, testing, android-edittext, robotium

Hi, I am currently working on robotium, I have did the sample test project with the following code:

```
public void testLoginToWhatsApp() throws InterruptedException { 
    solo.waitForActivity(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_CLASS);
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("WhatsApp"));
    solo.clickOnButton("Log In");
    solo.clearEditText(0);
    solo.enterText(0, "stest");
    solo.clearEditText(1);
    solo.enterText(1, "123456"); 
    final EditText Text = solo.getEditText(1);
    solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Text.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);
        }
    });
    solo.sleep(2000);
    solo.clickOnScreen(239, 761, 3); 
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("My Profile"));
    solo.sleep(3000);
}
```

My errorlog is as follows:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: EditText is not found!
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Waiter.waitForAndGetView(Waiter.java:501)
at com.jayway.android.robotium.solo.Solo.clearEditText(Solo.java:1783)
at com.WhatsApp.test.StartWhatsApp.testLoginToWhatsApp(StartWhatsApp.java:53)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)
```

I have given the code and already tried with the instructions given over [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/robotium-developers/4WTw2zTCF78) but still I cant clear this error log, any guidance where I made mistakes were welcome

Comment: How many edittext does your layout contains?

Comment: @vinaykumar There are only two text fieldsand another is buttonbut it is not shown It would be shown ifI press Go button of softkeyboard'That's why Iused Runnable anonymous classand use EditorInfo

Comment: ok, Instead of starting from 0 could you please try with 1 and 2 :  solo.enterText(1, "stest");

Comment: @vinaykumar ok let me give it a try

Comment: @vinaykumar tried but issue is same

Comment: Post your full class maybe you are setting up the activity incorrectly.

Comment: How are you starting the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

Even I was having similar issue, I had more than 6 text box which needed to be filled. Robotium was able to fill till 3 (index start : 0 ).
But it was not able to find the 4th index or the 5th one. 
It was throwing :

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<true> but was:<false>
```

at com.testJR.TestApk.testIfTheZipIsValid(TestApk.java:332)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)

But I was able to resolve the issue with solo.scrollUp();
Old Not code :

```
public void testIfTheZipIsValid() {
    UserActivities.fillTheFirstPage(solo);
    UserActivities.fillFullName(solo, "Prabhat_123");
    UserActivities.fillAdress(solo, "AAAA");
    UserActivities.fillState(solo, "UP");
    UserActivities.fillCity(solo, "Pune");
    UserActivities.fillZip(solo, String.valueOf("10"));
    UserActivities.fillPhone(solo, "8951592336");
    assertEquals(true, false);
}
```

New Working code :

```
public void testIfTheZipIsValid() {
    UserActivities.fillTheFirstPage(solo);
    UserActivities.fillFullName(solo, "Prabhat_123");
    UserActivities.fillAdress(solo, "AAAA");
    UserActivities.fillState(solo, "UP");
    UserActivities.fillCity(solo, "Pune");
    solo.scrollUp();
    UserActivities.fillZip(solo, String.valueOf("10"));
    solo.scrollUp();
    UserActivities.fillPhone(solo, "8951592336");
    assertEquals(true, false);
}
```

PS . This is not a permanent solution , I was lucky enough to figure out a way around it. This should be fixed in future releases.